# Is there any way to implement AutoMapper in BLL, separate from Web Application layer?

Tags: automapper, asp.net-core-3.1

Web UI - Models/ViewModels for Request and Response.

BLL - DTO

Data Accesss - Entity Design.

I am mapping Model to DTO in Web UI Layer and mapping DTO to Entity Design in BLL layer.

I have added below line in ConfigureServices method of Startup class.

`services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`

I am able to map in Web UI layer but while calling service layer it throw below Error:

`System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0 AutoMapper.IMapper.Map(System.Object)'.`

Can anyone suggest me the better way to keep separate BLL mapping profile and Web mapping profiles ?

Comment: If you add only one assembly in startup via `AddAutoMapper()` then AutoMapper will scan only that one assembly in search for mapping profiles. Simply add all the assemblies that contain your mapping profiles, not only the executing one. Maybe looking at the [source code of service collection extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L76) will help you understand how AutoMapper adds mapping profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great article
https://www.abhith.net/blog/using-automapper-in-a-net-core-class-library/
I resolve this by implementing ObjectMapper in BLL.